# Setting a widget's SizeHint

Tags: qt, sizehint

I have a `QtGui.QVBoxLayout` widget which exists inside a main `QtGui.QGridLayout` layout, which extends and centers the items all over the place (The left side)

I want the items to get stacked up at the top of the widget (The right side)

[image]

How can I achieve this? I know it has something to do with `SizeHint`, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Maybe you should try QVBoxLayout::setSpacing(int)

Comment: Have you tried `QBoxLayout::addStretch()` after adding the widgets to the layout?

Comment: @Blood It doesnt work

Comment: @PrisonMonkeys But I want to cancel the strech, not add it.

Comment: @iTayb You want to cancel the stretch between the widgets, which may be accomplished by adding stretch after the last widget has been added.

Comment: @PrisonMonkeys You are right, that worked. Please answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `QBoxLayout` will distribute the widgets evenly over the available space. The easiest way to keep all the widgets packed together at the top of a `QVBoxLayout`, is to add a stretchable spacing at the bottom that will push all the widgets up.

You can add a stretch that will take up as much space as it can with `QBoxLayout::addStretch()`.